# Palavras acentuadas com problemas

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Em muitos projetos `jsf` não lembro se já tive problema assim mas como mostra a imagem abaixo, a codificação não está correta. O problema está ocorrendo no `java` porque tenho palavras acentuadas na página e está tudo bem, no debug eu identifiquei que logo após ele setar o valor do texto já bagunça os caracteres. Alguém pode ajudar ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
JsfUtils.addWarnMessage("Atenção você deve selecionar o diretório primeiro!");
```

Comment: Para utilizar palavras acentuadas a codificação do arquivo tem que está em UTF-8.

Comment: Tenta colocar isso no topo do seu arquivo xhtml: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>`

Comment: Já tentei. Mas o problema é no java.

Comment: Pode ser a IDE ou o Server que você esta utilizando que está com a codificação diferente.

Comment: Para resolver estou usando um arquivo .properties.